# Xcode 11.3: can't select deployment target 13.3

Tags: swift, iphone, deployment

I upgraded to Xcode 11.3 but, Not able to select 13.3 from deployment target because of that my application is rejected by Apple Team. Can anyone help me regarding this issue.

Comment: Why would apple reject your app because you can't select 13.3 as the deployment target - mine's set to iOS 11.3 and we don't have any issues

Comment: actually i updated to Xcode 11.3 and uploaded to App Store. They gave me replay like your app is not supporting for 13.3. The issue i got to know is in Xcode deployment target is not showing 13.3 . upto 13.2 only visible. but iOS update to 13.3 is available. Not able to fix it. can you help me out

Comment: Nope, same problem - can't see 13.3 - only 13.2

Answer (score 0):

code which i've written in my VC is deprecated.That is the reason it is not working in latest iOS version. So  i updated with new code and works fine.